# am using Zync 909 tablet, i can't connect to pc to run my own android program

Tags: android, tablet

am developing android apps. In Eclipse, I need to run my program directly in my tablet. when I connected the device with pc(just can access the data I sd card) can't find the device to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:-

- Enable USB Debugging (Settings --> Security --> Developer Option -->
  Enable USB Debugging) in your tablet.
- If still doesn't work, try to reset the adb (DDMS Perspective -->
  Devices Tab --> Small Triangle on right side(Last option) --> Reset
  adb) in your Eclipse.

Comment: I done the first settings still didn't get. So try the 2nd settings and getting the following error:Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

Comment: Yeah it'll show it that way. But now the `ADB` is reset. Go to your `CMD`prompt --> traverse to the directory where `adb` is present and give this command. `adb devices`. It'll list all the devices connected to your system. See if your tablet is listed there or not.